# Web site architectural mix HTML and ASPX

Tags: asp.net, html, web

I have already a web site  written in Html but I want to add some dynamic contents in Asp.net. So I will add 2 or 3 aspx pages whit form to my project.So the question is: Is it necessary to convert my simple static HTML page to aspx to publish my web site? What is the best way in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to convert your HTML pages.

Static and dynamic content can live side by side without an issue.

Just add your ASPX pages - you may need to consider a migration path if you do have a static page that needs to be converted to a dynamic one (a permanent redirect should do).

Answer (score 1):

no, just go for the conversion to asp.net of those web pages which have the dynamic content.

Answer (score 1):

ASPX and plain HTML pages can live together happily because from a browser's point of view they all are html pages.

Web browsers don't understand ASP.NET. The content they understand is HTML. So when a browser requests for an .aspx link all that ASP.NET returns is plain HTML (with CSS and javascript, which browsers also understand). So at design time when you add an ASP.NET control, lets say a DropDownList, ASP.NET will render it as a `<select>` HTML tag.